# How to capture signalR connection string in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-4.0

I am getting error when script is executed in jmeter, because of signalr connection

I need to pass connectionToken and connectionData in the url as below.

"/Web/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=${connectionToken}&connectionData=${connectionData}"

i am able to capture ConnectionToken and passing that successfully. but, i am facing issue with connectionData, which looks like

[{"name":"alertshub"},{"name":"loggerhub"},{"name":"notificationhub"}]

How to capture and pass this.
Please find the screeshots

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SVbgp.png)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6uOe.png)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfvoe.png)

! [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r0Xz2.png)

not able to capture below connection string

connectionData: [{"name":"alertshub"},{"name":"loggerhub"},{"name":"notificationhub"}]

get method sends above connectionData as

GET //abc.com/Web/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22alertshub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22loggerhub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&_=1522754518635

and am getting the response connectionToken. i am able to extract connectionToken .

now, i need to send

GET //abc.com/Web/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&tid=10&connectionToken=%27FcFUJytTeVDsNq4EM5iY59NrIlAO4EK0nU%2BP9fDasBFDTA%2B78kpLr05HaQoqstQouqyFMP2hShwh2eHdiG%2BCsRq7wNHs70BVSkjJiLIdyePfB3SmMCmeZeZyvd1xzfnc%27&connectionData=%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522alertshub%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522loggerhub%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522notificationhub%2522%257D%255D%26_%3D1522754518635

It has valid connectionToken(extracted) but not the connectionData.

Response is  Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: %. Path '', line 0, position 0.

my question is how can i get this values, [{"name":"alertshub"},{"name":"loggerhub"},{"name":"notificationhub"}].

and next i need to post

POST //abc.com/Web/signalr/connect?transport=longPolling&clientProtocol=1.5&connectionToken=FcFUJytTeVDsNq4EM5iY59NrIlAO4EK0nU+P9fDasBFDTA+78kpLr05HaQoqstQouqyFMP2hShwh2eHdiG+CsRq7wNHs70BVSkjJiLIdyePfB3SmMCmeZeZyvd1xzfnc&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22alertshub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22loggerhub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D&_=1522754518635

as you can see here, it has valid connectionToken but not connectionData.

Response for this is : The ConnectionId is in the incorrect format.

[BlazeMeter1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Dabo.png)

[Blazemeter2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibDAY.png)

[Blazemeter3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zPe6.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the same method as you have used for connection token. 
It seems like your variable is not getting the required values. Are you using the same variables between two thread groups?

```
**-->Here request is encoded and connection data is also encoded.**
GET //abc.com/Web/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=**%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22alertshub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22loggerhub%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22notificationhub%22%7D%5D**&_=1522754518635
```

and am getting the response connectionToken. i am able to extract connectionToken .

now, i need to send

```
**-->Here again encoded connection data is further encoded.**
GET //abc.com/Web/signalr/connect?transport=serverSentEvents&clientProtocol=1.5&tid=10&connectionToken=%27FcFUJytTeVDsNq4EM5iY59NrIlAO4EK0nU%2BP9fDasBFDTA%2B78kpLr05HaQoqstQouqyFMP2hShwh2eHdiG%2BCsRq7wNHs70BVSkjJiLIdyePfB3SmMCmeZeZyvd1xzfnc%27&connectionData=**%255B%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522alertshub%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522loggerhub%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522name%2522%253A%2522notificationhub%2522%257D%255D%26**_%3D1522754518635
```

If I got it correct, then avoid encoding twice. In first and second screenshot you are encoding it twice. 
If "connectionData" is fixed then try "User defined variables" or if it is available in some response then capture there using regular expression and use it further.
I hope you are not getting error during data extraction.

Comment: @sunny_teo I think, i need search for connectionID

Comment: @Lakshmikanth :- Search if there is any connection ID which also needs to be co-related. You can also use fiddler to analyse the request and response while navigating and compare the same with jmeter request, header values, dynamic values & response.

Comment: @sunny_teo In below request : 


GET //abc.com/....notificationhub%22%7D%5D**&_=1522754518635

i need to append and send '=1522754518635' , its a incremental random number i guess. i need to figure it out. 

When i send this :
 GET //abc.com/Web/signalr/negotiate?clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=[{"name":"alertshub"},{"name":"loggerhub"}&_=152275451863

i ll receive connectionid, which is a uuid.

Sunny, do u have any suggestions

Comment: @Lakshmikanth 1. Run twice the request with fiddler and confirm if it is random or in a incremental order. 2. If random then use __Random() and if incremental then counter.

Comment: @sunny_teo Its an 13 digit increment number,  i analyzed using Blazemeter. But i dont know weather i can use any(random) 13 digit number and start incrementing. Please see the screenshots in my question. First two screenshot are for one session and third screenshot is new session(logged in again,to analyze the numbers)
appreciate ur suggestion.

Comment: @Lakshmikanth It is Unix epoch time in milliseconds. Option1- Check by sending a recently captured value manually. 2. Capture time stamp using regular expression just before the required request and use it.  3. Use ${__time()} function, it should do the trick. Reference EPOCH-->https://www.freeformatter.com/epoch-timestamp-to-date-converter.html , Time Function-->http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time

Comment: @sunny_teo I used ${__time()} and its working. Thank You.

Comment: @Lakshmikanth If it helped can you accept the answer.